# What is the term for telling someone unkindly to go do something

Tags: imperatives

There are phrases we use to tell a person to go do something, elsewhere, away from us, that might cause injury or misfortune. There is not necessarily an expectation that they will do the thing. It is mostly meant to reinforce that the person is not welcome, and invites them to occupy their time somewhere else.

Examples:

"go take a hike",
"go pound salt",
"go fly a kite in a thunderstorm",
"take a long walk off a short pier",
"piss off",
"go to heck",
etc..

Is there a word to describe this type of statement? Was thinking something like 'antagonistic imperative'?

Comment: Somewhat more general is the verb *tell off,* which [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell%20off) defines as "reprimand; excoriate". However, if you tell someone off, it doesn't have to involve imperatives.

Comment: More specifically, perhaps, a *[curt] **dismissal***. Telling someone off, reprimanding them, etc., don't have that implication of ***Begone**! Take yourself and your problems **elsewhere, away from me**!* Note that ***to dismiss*** does usually allude to *literal* "sending away", but it can be used more metaphorically as simply ***ignore, don't take into account***.

Comment: It's getting a bit dated now, but plenty of people still say ***Be off with you**!* for imperative ***Go away**!* And there are any number of "quaint" imperatives with much the same meaning - e.g. *[Why don't you] **take a long walk** [off a short pier]?*

Comment: There's a [Grammarist post](https://grammarist.com/idiom/take-a-hike/) on the similar "take a hike" but it doesn't give a name for it (it also features in several dictionaries). Nor does [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=50944) discussing similar terms in Japanese. There is quite a lot written about rude words these days, but I can't find anything to answer the question. Maybe it doesn't have a name.